# How to bind two SimpleDoubleProperty's with a mathematical operation?

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, binding

I can bind a SimpleDoubleProperty to some text easy enough:

```
getSomeTextProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%,.0f", getSomeDoubleProperty()));
```

Is it possible to do something to the effect of:

```
getSomeTextProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%,.0f", getSomeDoubleProperty()+getAnotherDoubleProperty()));
```

The idea being whenever someDoubleProperty *or* anotherDoubleProperty changes, the text updates with the addition of both of them (or subtraction, or multiplication etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StringExpression` created by `Bindings.format` is updated when one of the arguments is an `ObservableValue` that changes. `DoubleProperty.add` creates such an object.

```
DoubleProperty v1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
DoubleProperty v2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
StringExpression sb = Bindings.format("%,.3f", v1.add(v2));
System.out.println(sb.get());
sb.addListener((a, b, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
v1.set(3);
v2.set(5.5);
```

Comment: Can this be extended for three property's? Or even extend to n property's?

Comment: In case of this number of properties, `Bindings.createDoubleBinding` may be a better option, but in general calling `add` `n-1` times should work...

Comment: as in v1.add(v2.add(v3.add(v4))); etc ?

Comment: @AlwaysNeedingHelp For "completeness", another way to do the same thing as in the answer would be: `v1.add(v2).asString("%,.3f");`. As for three or more properties, rather than `v1.add(v2.add(v3.add(v4)));` you can do `v1.add(v2).add(v3).add(v4);` which I think is more clear.